# Where to Place Custom Classes in Joomla (Component, Plugin, Module?)

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-component

I am new to Joomla (a seasoned WP dev) and I have just barely managed to wrap my head around the components and the plugins.

The thing is, that I want to include a shared component (a class), that should be callable from both the component and the plugin.

Any ideas? A library maybe? Can I bundle a library in a Joomla installer [Package](http://docs.joomla.org/Package) in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a `lib_yourlib.xml` file in the root directory and specify :

```
<extension type="library">
<files folder="yourlib">
```

it should be installable like any package, and it will be copied in `libraries/yourlib` after installation.

Comment: That is inside the root directory of a component or a plugin?

Comment: I mean where should I put the library installation, not where it will go aftewards. Basically, should I put a library inside the plugin or inside the component?

Comment: You can create a library package like mentionned above and install it together with your component / plugin. It will be installed in `libraries/your_lib` and you can use it in the component and plugin from there. If your plugin doesn't work without the component, then you can put it in the component.